# Using the output of an inputBox as an input for an inputSlider in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I plan to create an app including an Inputbox where you can choose a "scenario". Depending on the choosen scenario, an inputSlider below the Box should change its initial value, but it should still be possible to change this value and make further calculations with it. 
I tried to print the inital value to compare it to the slider, but even through the inital value changes, the slider doesn't change. It makes sense though because the inputSlider is not reactive, while the print of the inital value above is… Now I do not know how I can bring "reactivity" into the Slider. Any suggestions?

Here is what I already tried:

```
 library(shiny)
library(DT)

dropinput <- 1

ui <- fluidPage(

inputPanel(
#InputBox
selectInput(inputId = "szenarios", label="Szenarios:", 
            choices=c("calculated"="calculated","shiny"="shiny"))), 

textOutput("dropinput"),  #Print of the Inital value of the sliderInput calculated from the Output of the Box

sliderInput("EU_slider_DF", label = "EU_slider", min = 0, 
                          max = 3,step=0.001, value =dropinput))


server<-function(input,output){
  output$dropdown<-renderPrint({input$szenarios})
  output$dropinput<- reactive({if (input$szenarios=="shiny") dropinput<- 2     else if (input$szenarios=="calculated") dropinput<- 3 })}



#Load the App
shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: There is no "dropdown` labeled element, so you cannot use `output$dropdown`. An output argument in the server expects some sort of rendering, you are using reactive which does not work. You want to use `updateSliderInput` if you want to update `EU_slider_DF`. A ui value will not automatically update when `dropinput` is re-evaluated, so `value = dropinput` will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in the ui, change the `value` of the sliderInput, ""EU_slider_DF" to `value=1`

Then change your server to follow this

```
#Add session argument so we can push updates
server<-function(input,output,session){

#Output to our text output, render is reactive so directly use input$_
output$dropinput<-renderPrint({input$szenarios})

#Observe event used to monitor changes anytime the selectinput is changed
observeEvent(input$szenarios,{
if (input$szenarios=="shiny"){ (dropinput<- 2)
}else if (input$szenarios=="calculated") { (dropinput<- 3)
}else{ (dropinput<-1) }

#updates slider based on what is selected
updateSliderInput(session,"EU_slider_DF",value=dropinput, min = 0, 
                          max = 3,step=0.001)
 })
}
```

Comment: Thank you that does perfectly what I wanted! The observeEvent function in combination with the updateSliderInput function is something I have to remember!

Comment: @Michelle no problem, you can also use`observe` which works a bit different as it wont wait for any criteria to run and will just go when anything inside it changes, you can look at the example here https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateSliderInput.html